# Hibernate, Delete a parent row when the foreign key constraint exists

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, mapping

I have 2 entities Category and Publication. The relation I have here is that every Publication is having a Category.

Something like this

```
create table category(
id INTEGER not null auto_increment,
name varchar(255) not null,
primary key (id)
);


CREATE TABLE PUBLICATION(
ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
TITLE varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CONTENT VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
CATEGORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
primary key(ID),
foreign key (CATEGORY_ID) references CATEGORY (ID)
);
```

and the entity objects

```
package com.java.bricks.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;



    @Entity
    @Table(name="PUBLICATION")
    public class PublicationEntity implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name="ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long publicationId;

        @Column(name="TITLE")
        private String title;

        @Column(name="CONTENT")
        private String content;


        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY_ID")
        private CategoryEntity category;


        public Long getPublicationId() {
            return publicationId;
        }
        public void setPublicationId(Long publicationId) {
            this.publicationId = publicationId;
        }
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }
        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }
        public CategoryEntity getCategory() {
            return category;
        }
        public void setCategory(CategoryEntity category) {
            this.category = category;
        }



    }
```

and the category entity

```
package com.java.bricks.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="CATEGORY")
public class CategoryEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long categoryId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    public String categoryName;


    public Long getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }
    public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }
    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }
    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }



}
```

Now when I delete the Publication record, the publication record gets deleted successfully. this works fine. But now what I want is that when I delete the category record, it should remove the category record (parent) and all the foreign key records in the publication table as well.

How can I do that ? I did cascade.all but I still get the same error.

Also, is it even right to give access to the user to delete the category when you have foreign key records ? If yes how can it be done in this example

thanks

Comment: When you say you tried cascade.all, did you add that to the category or publication?

Comment: I added cascade to publication, I do not have a publication instance inside Category so I did not add it there.. I added cascade to Publication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate will typically look only at the class that is getting deleted instead of scanning the entire entity graph. If there is no explicit link in that class, then it won't do anything. Since Category does not have a FK, you use the mappedBy property in the annotation, and it will look for an instance variable with that name. When it finds the instance variable, it will be able to infer about the relation between the entities.

Think of cascade as what operations flow from this entity to the mapped entities. When you delete a category entity, it looks at the publication mapping, and sees that delete should cascade to that publication.

```
package com.java.bricks.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="CATEGORY")
public class CategoryEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long categoryId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    public String categoryName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Publication publication;    

    public Long getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }
    public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }
    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }
    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }



}
```

Comment: but then by doing this am i not setting the relationships between Category and Publication as bidirectional ? would that be a true statement if I do what you have just said. Also what is the recommended practice for one to one mappings bi-directional or uni-directional ?

Comment: Right now the relationship is one-direction(publication to category). Adding the mapping to category will make it bi-directional. I always add the mapping even if I don't need it immediately. It makes the entity document the relationship in case I forget.

Comment: Hi @J-Bar, I did what you mentioned above, so now when I delete the category, the Publications also gets deleted. But now I have another problem when I delete the publication I get an error       org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.java.bricks.entity.PublicationEntity#18]; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.java.bricks.entity.PublicationEntity#18]

Comment: full stacktrace rg.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.java.bricks.entity.PublicationEntity#18]
 org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.forceFlush(SessionImpl.java:1220)
 org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:188)
 org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
 org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateE